# ar file extract in java

Tags: java, compression

Anyone have any links to a class or package for extracting ar packages in java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apace commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) supports ar according to their page. I don't use it for ar, but for other types it works well.

Comment: Commons Compress defines an API for working with ar, cpio, tar, zip, gzip and bzip2 files.